# 1996 Chevy Silverado losing power

Tags: chevrolet, idle, silverado

My 1996 Chevy Silverado started jumping when at idle, then when moving started to lose its power when you step on the gas. While idling, you have to put it in neutral and keep foot on the gas until you start to move again. What could be the problem?

Comment: Well, it could be a number of things, or a combination of them. We are going to need you to help us help you by giving more information. First, get the codes read and tell us what they are, if there are any. What engine does the truck have? We also need to know when the last time a tune up was done. There is [more information here](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1470/4939) about what we need to know and why.

Comment: Sounds like a Misfire or fuel problem. Check spark plugs & fuel pressure as a start, then post again on if that helped.

Comment: make sure you check spark plugs,fuel filter, and fuel pressure, I also know in a couple of cases oil pressure can mess you up as well. Is it stock?

Comment: I agree with Kyler...check the fuel delivery. Start at the filter, *especially* if you can't remember when it was last replaced. When you remove the old filter, if you can't blow air through it, it's clogged..

Answer (score 0):

Does it do it every time or just sometimes? If it does it just sometimes, it could be the ignition switch. If you notice that the PRNDL light goes out when it happens, then check the ignition switch.

If it happens all the time, could be the intake manifold.